# Railscasts #228 - Sortable Table Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-sortable, railscasts

I am following Ryan Bates' railscast on Sortable Table Columns and I have successfully gotten a column to sort ascending and descending.

My table is more complex than in the Railscast because I have columns from different tables.

```
# controller
@cars = Car.find(:all).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).includes(:manufacturers)


#view
<%= sortable "age" %>
```

How do you add sortable columns for related tables such as manufacturers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Got it fixed with something like:

```
 <%= sortable "manufacturers.name", "Manufacturer name" %>
 <%= sortable "cars.age", "Age" %>
```

The sort function in the application_controller should be something like this:

```
 def sort_column
     ['manufacturers.name', 'cars.age'].include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : 'cars.age'
 end
```

Comment: Hi Cristian, it's not working unfortunately. It does work within the same table but not using your code above to sort on other columns. Are you sure this exact code worked?

Comment: Hi Christian, I played around for 30 minutes and started to get it working - I needed some controller and view tweaks to get it. Here's the final challenge: one of my sortable fields is a class method of cars entitled 'efficiency', which is a calculation based on two of cars' other fields (divide one field by the other). It isn't finding cars.efficiency :)

Comment: You might want to try and store the 'efficiency' in another column. That would work faster and simpler. Basically a before filter sets that value. The sorting should be obvious afterwards.

Comment: I have a problem in sort as i am using Mongodb as database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090621/sortable-table-columns-is-not-working-working-in-mongodb I think i may get answer here. As problem is solved here. Hope to get answer ..