# Sortable -table columns is not working in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am using rails cast video http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax  .
It works fine for Mysql database. i want to implement this in Mongodb.
my application_helper.rb file is like this

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
  end
```

my products_controller.rb file is like this

```
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  def index
   @products = Product.search(params[:search]).order_by(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)


  end


private

  def sort_column
    Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

My product.rb model is like this

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name, type: String
  field :price, type: String
  field :released_at, type: String

  def self.search(search)
    if search
       where(name: /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i) 
     else
       scoped
    end
  end
end
```

It works fine in Mysql database but for Mongodb it throws error like

```
undefined method `column_names' for Product:Class
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:81:in `sort_column'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

I messed up. I am new to Mongodb.

Comment: Looks like you didn't define a class method named `column_names` inside your `Product` model?

Comment: I have edited my question with Product model also. where do i have to define this? can u edit my question..

Comment: MongoDb is document driven, not columns. What would column names map to in a structured document?

Comment: can u edit my question for my result. I am new to Mongodb. Hope u will

Comment: `def self.column_names #here comes your code for this particular method  end`

Comment: @WPCoder, MongoDB is document driven by used with the Mongoid driver within Rails you create Models which have defined columns, it is true that one column could hold inside it more hashes of different type, such is the document driven databases but regmiprem's question refers to the basic fields in the Product collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoid doesn't support a column_names method by itself.
What you need to do is supply one yourself, add this to your model.

```
  def self.column_names
    self.fields.collect { |field| field[0] }
  end
```